# Returning first key of a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap in a class called Yoghurts

```
Map<Integer, Integer>French = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

I then made accessor methods, so that the collection could be accessed from another class

I now want to GET the first key entered, but I am not sure how to do this.

```
 int location = Yoghurts.getHashMap().entrySet().iterator().next();
```

however this returns the error incompatible types

Comment: How are we supposed to answer a question from you with a name like that?

Comment: In your question title you ask how to get first key, in your question you ask how to enter it. Please make it more obvious what you want to achieve

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov It's clear that he wants to retrieve the first key entered.

Comment: It doesn't say how to enter it? "I now want to GET the first key entered"

Comment: The first key entered, as in the key of the first key-value pair you added to the hash map?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible, as the key sets is not guaranteed to return the first key you entered. Sets do not have an order.

Comment: I thought it was possible with a LinkedHashMap specifically?

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're using `entrySet()`, whose members are of type `Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>`. Use `getKey()` on the result of the iterator, or use `map.keySet().iterator().next();`

Answer (score 1):

It is much clearer where your mistake is if you assign variables to each of the method call results:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = Yoghurts.getHashMap();
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> iterator = entrySet.iterator();
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
```

What is left to do is to extract the key from the [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html):

```
int location = entry.getKey();
```

Note that you are also unboxing the `Integer` key to an `int` here, which could throw an exception if the key is null (I believe LinkedHashMap supports null keys).

Comment: This is unnecessarily wordy and really doesn't help in this case. An IDE will show you the type of each method call, and it's clear in any case what the error is. However, you're correct that both `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`, which is based on it, permit `null` keys, and the person using the code needs to be aware of that.